# Stop toggle in treenode in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, toggle, treenode

i have a treeview in winforms . When i double click on treenode ,its childnode gets disappear .Again when i click on that very node its child nodes gets expand. Any body please help me out.

Comment: is there any code on double click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disable double click alltogether you will have handle directly the `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` `(0x0203)`. To  do that create a `MyTreeView` control inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` and override the `WndProc(ref Message m)` method.

```
 public class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x203) { m.Result = IntPtr.Zero; } //Makes the control ignore double licks`
        else base.WndProc(ref m);
    }              
};
```

This solution will disable completely double clicks on all the `TreeView` control. If you can live with that, this solution will do.

Comment: Thanx Buddy for your answer.As I am Begineer in visual studio,I don't know where this code is to place.

Comment: @Prakash Kunwar: You have to create your own `MyTreeView`. As I show you in my answer, create a new `class` and extend `TreeView`: `public class MyTreeView: TreeView {...}`. Now you have a class that smells, looks and behaves exactly the same as a `TreeView`. Inside this class you need to override the virtual `WndProc(ref Message m)` method like I show you. In your `Form` add a `MyTreeView` **NOT** a `TreeView` and you are done. VS will show by default any controls you create under `%project name% Components` in the Form desginer's Toolbox. Just drag it from there onto your Form like always.